# Text squeeze on flutter web, facebook in app browser

Tags: flutter, facebook, inappbrowser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jURC9.jpg)

I'm having that problem on flutter web, this is happening only on Facebook in-app browser. any ideas?
When I open my website on google or safari I don't have that problem, seems to be only that is happening on in-app browser.

I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.